# Changing the font size of a list in a rich text editor: List-points slide away

Tags: html, qt, pyqt4

In a qtextedit with html I am changing the fontsize via the mousewheel.
It should change the size of each character, e.g.+1 or -1.
It works, slowly, but it works. The problem is now if I change the size of a html list (created via QTextCursor.createList()). As you see in the picture, the "Test" after resizing always starts at the same position (as intended), but the black points move. I'd like them to stay on the same position no matter how big the text is. I have no clue how to do that, I already tried setMarging, setIndent, setTextIndent...

[image: The list is indented wrong]

```
def change_fontsize(self, direction):
    cur=self.textedit.textCursor()
    oldPosition=cur.position()

    if cur.hasSelection():
        begin=cur.anchor()
        end=cur.position()
        if begin>end:
            helper=end
            end=begin
            begin=helper
    else:
        cur.select(QTextCursor.Document)
        begin=0
        plainText=self.textedit.toPlainText()
        end=len(plainText)

    for i in range(begin,end):
        cur.setPosition(i)
        cur.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        fmt=cur.charFormat()
        charSize=fmt.fontPointSize()
        if direction=="up":
            fmt.setFontPointSize(charSize+1)
        else:
            fmt.setFontPointSize(charSize-1)
        cur.mergeCharFormat(fmt)
```